# How can I get mouse coordinates in Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: grid, mouseevent, edit, blazor-webassembly, mouse-coordinates

I create a generic grid component, in the last column, I put an icon with dots that should open the edit menu for every row, like this...

[image]

How can I calculate mouse coordinates to open the edit window near clicked row edit icon??
On the edit window I need to show the Edit, Delete, Move buttons.

Comment: While you can get mouse coords you shouldn't want to. Avoid X,Y positioning amap.

Comment: The Edit menu should be activate _inside_ that row and then you can use CSS to make it float or something.